# C++ Singly Linked List text file

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am pretty new to linked lists and they are confusing me very much right now. I need to write a code that reads a text file of integers into a singly linked list. I have already written the code to read in the text file and it works properly, but now I need to read the integers from the file into the list using the following struct. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
 struct Item {
      int val;
      Item* next;
    };

Item (int v, Item *p, Item *n)
    { val = v; prev = p; next = n; }
};

void list(Item *&head, int val)
{
    Item *newptr = new Item;
    newptr->val = v;
    newptr->next = NULL;    

    if (head == NULL) 
        head = newptr;
        else 
        Item *temp = head;
        while(temp->next){
            temp = temp->next;  
        }

        temp->next = newptr;
}
```

Comment: Search around in SO on how to read a file into a linked list. Maybe this one will help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916229/read-txt-file-into-a-sorted-linked-list-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916229/read-txt-file-into-a-sorted-linked-list-c)

Comment: Just updated with what I tried so far. Not really sure what I'm doing/supposed to be doing.